# C++ Container selection/choices

Tags: c++, collections, stl

There is plenty of discussion on StackOverflow and other sites on what type of C++ container to use, with the not so shocking conclusion "it depends on your needs".

Currently i'm using std::list on my interfaces, however i have no direct requirement on lists as opposed to vectors or deques; and in there lies my question.

I can't say what my requirements will be down the line. Todays its a list, tomorrow... who knows?

I've been toying with the idea of creating a wrapper class 'Collection' which does nothing more than expose the STL containers interface allowing me to alter the internals without breaking my interfaces if the need arises.

Is this worth the hassle?
Should i just suck it up and make a decision on my current needs?

Any opinions?

Cheers,
Ben

EDIT:

Thread safety is important.

The recompilation of code that consumes the interface is unacceptable.

Comment: Well i may need to change the interfaces... i may not? It will break all my plugins and require them to be recompiled if i do. So my thinking is that yes i should create this Collection class.

Comment: The site is presently down, but look here once it comes back up: [STL container class choice](http://www.jamesonwilliams.com/bin/stl_container_class_choice.png). As an even easier choice, in case you really don't know your requirements, just use `std::vector`. It works for everything and it mostly works kind of efficiently too. If you eventually end up needing to insert a lot at the beginning or in the middle, you can still switch to `deque` or `list` later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write such class if only you are going to make an option in your program to use different container type or create some kind of run-time optimization but in general you should know what the container is used for and so you know how it's used and that leads to what your needs are.

Don't make a class that you use just because you don't understand different containers because it's a waste of resources. In such case you should learn more about a few main container types, such as list, vector, queue, probably map, and use whenever they are needed. The only reason why there are so many of them is that different situations require different containers to make programming easier and code more efficient. For example lists are good if you put and remove a lot while vector is faster if you do more of reading. Queues are good when there is a need to do things in exact order (priority_queue is the same, by the way, except you can use a specific order), maps are good for hashing current state or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You should write your code generically. But instead of defining a generic `Container`, use the STL way of decoupling algorithms from containers (iterators). Since you want to link dynamically, read [this article](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html), and you may find some things in boost (any_range...).

Comment: If i had the method 'Iterator DataSource::select_objects()' and called it twice from different threads what would be the outcome? How would i maintain the state in a thread safe manner? It would appear to be far more complicated then just returning a container of objects, no? Am i missing something?

Comment: @Ben: yes, you're missing something. How do you do it now? `list<obj> select_objects()`? Then define a range that holds that `list` and wrap it into `any_range`. The functionality is now equivalent. What's better is that now you can do the computation 'on-the-fly' while you're iterating through the range, eliminating any container copies.

Comment: You can also change to `void select_objects(output_range)` and write to the parameter.

Comment: Thanks nice to know :D. Currently i return the list<obj> then call for(auto obj : objects) {}. Just to be difficult i don't really want to bring in a dependency that can resolve the issue without it at little overhead. Sorry i know this makes me sound really difficult. However i value your input and thank you for your time and solution. I think i'm settling on Valdo's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a single container and want to change its type quickly, use a `typedef` as recommended by @icabod.

If you're writing algorithms that should work with different containers selected at compile-time, then implement them as `template` code on containers, or, if possible, iterators.

Only if you need to select a container type at run-time you should implement a polymorphic `Container` or `Collection` class + subclasses.